# How to securely store an AES key on the iPhone

Tags: ios, security, commoncrypto

So I was going about implementing AES encryption of data on an iPhone app, when I was puzzled by how to store the encryption key. I can easily enough encrypt data using a user-entered password, the encryption key. However, if I store the key unencrypted, the encryption is useless as anyone with access could easily enough decrypt the data with the readily-available encryption key. I could encrypt the key, but then there would be another unencrypted key floating around and someone could just follow the chain down to the data. It seemed clear that I could not store the key, so I thought that I could have the key be only in the user's mind. It would be very secure, but I would have no way to check if the decryption worked correctly and all data would be lost in the event that the user forgot their password, which is unacceptable.

Essentially, how can I securely store an encryption key for AES?

I'm sure this situation has been encountered before, as other questions have shown, but they seemed web-focused. I am interested in an iPhone-centric solution, potentially using CommonCrypto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, don't store the password. You can still store a hash of the password separately and test against that to see if it's the correct password.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about if the user forgets their password?

Comment: @Regan, they'll have to delete the application data and start over. I think this is standard functionality. If you forget your passcode (unlock PIN) on your iPhone, you know what your options are? Reset the phone. You lose anything not synced/saved elsewhere. To the system you forgetting your password is the same as an attacker not knowing the password. What are you encrypting? Can you store a copy on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are interested in saving this in the Keychain as a generic service? There is a nice Objective-C wrapper for the Keychain services called [SSKeychain](https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain).

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice open source kit i use in my projects for storing secure data in key chain.

[PDKeychainBindingsController](https://github.com/carlbrown/PDKeychainBindingsController)